# Achieving coloring picture effect

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I want to achieve coloring picture effect on the photo and asking for help with computer vision techniques as I am newbie in this area. I started out with bilaterial filter and min filter. But I am stucked what to do next. I use opencv with python for prototyping. Is there any patterns that might help me to achieve this? Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Can you give a better description of the result than "coloring picture effect"?

Comment: I guess something as close as possible to something like that http://www.allcoloring.com/images/cheetah-coloring-pages-15.jpg

Comment: @EgorLakomkin type in Google: Canny edge detector.

Comment: @Astor, thank you for your reply. Maybe you can recommend some image preprocessing stages before applying canny edge detector? I guess it might work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

- Convert image to grayscale
- Apply [Canny edge detector](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) or [Sobel filter](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "Non-photorealistic rendering". In its simplest form, it is what Astor suggested you. But there are many studies in this field, starting with automatic creation of sketches to complex cartoon-like effects and more.

[Here](http://www.mi.auckland.ac.nz/tech-reports/MItech-TR-65.pdf) is a paper on this topic, and another one [here](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Paul.Rosin/npr.html), but you can find more by googling `"Non photorealistic rendering"`